# Dephi read registry on Windown 7 x64

Tags: delphi, registry, delphi-7, windows-7-x64

I have value in registry (Windows 7 x64):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html]
@="ChromeHTML"
```

Then i read via my ServiceApplication on Delphi 7:

```
Reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_ALL_ACCESS or KEY_WOW64_32KEY);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;

    Reg.OpenKey('.html', False);
    Default := Reg.ReadString('');
```

I have got `htmlfile` in my `Default` variable.

How can i get correct value?

ps: Same code in destop application reads correct value.

Comment: What made you choose KEY_ALL_ACCESS in order to read? And why use KEY_WOW64_32KEY in a 32 bit process? And what can you do with that key from a service app anyway which cannot show GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is a merged view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724498.aspx) of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` keys, where a value present in `HKCU` has priority over a corresponding value present in `HKLM`.  By default, a service does not run in the same user account as a desktop app does.  So, for the user account that the service is actually running as, either `htmlfile` exists in that user's `HKCU` key, or no value exists in `HKCU` but `htmlfile` does exist in the `HKLM` key instead.

In order for the service to see the same data that the desktop app sees, the service has to access the Registry as the same user.  You need to either:

1. configure the service in the SCM to run as that user account.
2. have the service dynamically impersonate the user account using `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()` or similar function, then open that user's `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key normally.
3. have the service dynamically obtain a token to the user account, such as from `LogonUser()` or `OpenProcessToken()`, then use the [`LoadUserProfile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762281.aspx) and [`RegOpenUserClassesRoot()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724899.aspx) functions to access that user's `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key.